# Is there a way to merge two mutated dataframes together?

Tags: r, merge, mutate

so I basically have two dataframes mutated from a single dataframe 'original_data':

I used the mutate function on 'original data' to keep only values <= 600 seconds, all the other values would return as NA, this is stored in 'new_data_one'.

I then used the mutate function on 'original data' again to keep a single value >600, all the other values would return as NA, this is stored in 'new_data_two'.

Both of these dataframe retained their structure, so something like this:

'original_data'

```
   1  2   3   4   5
R1 80 98 150 599 650
R2 90 95 254 725 905
R3 93 96 540 650 780
```

'new_data_one'

```
   1  2   3   4   5
R1 80 98 150 599 NA
R2 90 95 254 NA  NA
R3 93 96 540 NA  NA
```

'new_data_two'

```
   1  2   3  4  5
R1 NA NA NA NA  650
R2 NA NA NA 725  NA
R3 NA NA NA 650  NA
```

How do I merge the two mutated dataframes ('new_data_one' and 'new_data_two'), so I get an output of something like this (that essentially retains the same col/row structures)?

'desired_merged_dataframe'

```
   1  2   3   4   5
R1 80 98 150 599 650
R2 90 95 254 725 NA
R3 93 96 540 650 NA
```

Comment: If your overall aim is to just keep the first > 600 value in each row, then you could do: `original_data[col(original_data) > max.col(original_data > 600, "first")] <- NA`

Answer (score 4):

```
replace(df1, is.na(df1), df2[is.na(df1)])

   X1 X2  X3  X4  X5
R1 80 98 150 599 650
R2 90 95 254 725  NA
R3 93 96 540 650  NA
```

---

```
library(tidyverse)
map2_df(df1, df2, coalesce)

# A tibble: 3 × 5
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    80    98   150   599   650
2    90    95   254   725    NA
3    93    96   540   650    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)

new_data_one %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ coalesce(., new_data_two[[cur_column()]])))

  X1 X2  X3  X4  X5
R1 80 98 150 599 650
R2 90 95 254 725  NA
R3 93 96 540 650  NA
```